# for loop in javaScript not running

Tags: javascript

I have this fizzbuzz game I am working on. it works properly with the for loop commented out as in this example, but If I uncomment the for loop only the fizz condition works, and nothing else. I have a pen here: http://codepen.io/lucky500/pen/GJjVEO

```
//for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
    resultBox.innerHTML = "fizzbuzz";
} else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    resultBox.innerHTML = "fizz";
}   else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    resultBox.innerHTML = "buzz";
} else if (i > 100)  {
    alert("Please enter a number from 1 to 100");

} else {

    resultBox.innerHTML = i;
}
// clear input
input.value = " ";
}
//}
```

Comment: My guess is, It is working, Except that you are overwriting the content of resultBox every time. The last element in the loop is `99` which results in a `fizz`, hence the result. Try to append instead of overwriting the value. To verify this, change the value of `i<100 ` to `i<151`

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but you have a condition that is never met in your loop.  If the loop is for 1 through 99, you will never hit the line for `if (i > 100) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting the content each time with:

```
resultBox.innerHTML = ...
```

You need to concat the results instead:

```
resultBox.innerHTML += ...
```

That's why you only see one (the last) output.

---

See it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJMKOe
(you need to fix the input though)

Comment: this isn't a good idea, you will be accessing the DOM everytime you loop...super slow on IE and other browsers

Comment: @abc123 Optimizing the DOM wasn't the question here... I just answered it by showing what's wrong and giving a solution. Sure, there are tons of improvements possible here. Btw. I don't think 100 writes to the DOM are that bad... even for IE.

Comment: Good idea or not, this is the only answer to OP's question.  @Shomz you could append your answer with a suggestion to improve performance.

Comment: @JasonWilczak, I'll try to stay within the scope of the question. Suggesting all the optimizations will open a whole new can of worms. And as I said, I don't think 100 DOM writes would crash IE.

Comment: i do see that this answers the question, but it will end up with a result if input is `5` of `12fizz34` which isn't really what the OP wants....at a minimum he wants `12fizz34buzz` and likely wants new lines between each...

Comment: @abc123 If you actually took half of the time you took to bash my answer to actually just run the example, you'd see the output for input `5` is exactly what you asked for... even with the new lines...

Comment: Your update to your answer just showed up (literally, not trying to "bash" your answer.  trying to help someone who is doing a simple fizzbuzz question.  Sorry if you are taking offense, as this is now a conversation and not a comment.  I will only say, SO doesn't like links to demos without the code also in the answer.

Comment: @abc123 I haven't made any updates to the answer. Anyway, as I said, I just answered why OP wasn't seeing more than one output when doing the loop (even though he'd get `12fizz...` as you said). Anything else is out of the scope of the question, and the example I gave was just to show it's working. Both answers and questions on SO should be as direct as possible.  And yes, I agree we could spent quite a while to optimize this to make it run ideally... but again, not my main concern as I haven't broken anything, just gave a direct answer with a complementary live code.

Comment: sounds good, I didn't downvote this...just so you know I agree this answer is correct.  I was just trying to help out nothing else, also i guess i didn't see the link...

Comment: No worries, man, I thought you hated my whole answer as you said it wasn't a good idea in your 1st comment. I get it now, you just wanted to suggest an optimization.

Comment: Thanks Shomz and @abc123 for the help. And yes, it did fix my loop. When you say accessing the DOM repeatly, do you suggest that I store the resultBox.innerHTML in a var, or I shouldn't use the innerHTML on this case altogether?

Comment: @Lucky500 I would suggest making a `var result = ""` then instead of `innerHTML += ___` use `result += _____` then after the for loop do a `innerHTML = result`

Comment: You're welcome, @Lucky500! Yes, abc123's idea will improve the performance and is generally a good practice to follow all the time.